# Can a Netty NIO channel be writable but not connected?

Tags: java, netty

I have a handler that receives an `channelInterestChanged` callback then tests the channel's `isWritable()` method in that callback and fires a `writeRequest` event downstream if it is.

Sometimes if this occurs right as the channel is being opened the channel throws an exception event with the cause as `java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException`.

Should `isWritable() == true` assume `isConnected() == true` or did I screw this up?

Example:

```
@Override
public void channelInterestChanged(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
        ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
    MyMessage msg;
    while(ctx.getChannel().isWritable()){
        msg = queue.poll();
        Channels.write(ctx, Channels.succeededFuture(ctx.getChannel()), msg);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:696)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:421)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:116)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:733)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:65)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:733)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:65)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:733)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:694) <--- this call is guarded by `isWritable()`
    at foo.bar.MyHandler.channelInterestChanged(MyHandler.java:44) <--- My handler
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:61)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelInterestChanged(Channels.java:361)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels$3.run(Channels.java:349)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.ChannelRunnableWrapper.run(ChannelRunnableWrapper.java:41)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processEventQueue(AbstractNioWorker.java:373)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:254)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connectable and writable are the same condition under the hood. Make sure you test connectable first, and when it fires complete the connection and lose all interest in the connectable state/event if it succeeds. Don't register interest in writing until the connection completes.

Comment: I added a test for `isConnected()` which fixed the problem. I guess I (wrongly) assumed that the channel can't be writable if it isn't connected.

Comment: @Dev I'm not familiar with the Netty API, but under the NIO hood you or it should have called `SocketChannel.finishConnect()` when `OP_CONNECT` fired, and only registered `OP_WRITE` if `finishConnect()` returned true.